# Telling my backup script in windows to "mount everything that's supposed to be mounted."

Tags: windows, batch-file, mount, drive

I have a backup script that works. I won't put in the entire script, because I don't think it's necessary, but it looks like this:

```
set backup_dir=R:\__MYBACKUPS

REM *** <<< Right here, I want to have a command that says "Mount everything you know how to mount"

if not exist %backup_dir% (
    echo The backup directory does not exist.
    echo Making the backup directory %backup_dir%
)

call :get_datetime_stamp

set BACKUPNAME=%backup_dir%\bak%DATEANDTIME%.zip
set default_to_backup="c:\Users\%username%\documents\*.doc*" "c:\Users\%username%\documents\*.csv" "c:\Users\%username%\documents\*.xls*" "c:\Users\%username%\documents\*.pdf" ^
    "c:\Users\%username%\documents\*.ppt*" "c:\Users\%username%\documents\*.txt" 

set what_to_backup=%default_to_backup% "c:\Users\%username%\etc"

set zip_program="c:\Program Files\winzip\winzip64.exe"
set zip_parameters=-min -a -r
echo EXECUTING THE FOLLOWING BACKUP COMMAND:

echo %zip_program% %zip_parameters% %BACKUPNAME% %what_to_backup%
%zip_program% %zip_parameters% %BACKUPNAME% %what_to_backup%
```

It works fine, if I mount the R drive.  The way I normally do this is when I login I manually go to the explorer window and just click on the R drive ... and that action magically "connects" the R shared network drive. HOWEVER, what I would prefer to do is have the script "mount the drive." I don't want to go in and click all the network drives to connect them.  I don't want to specify all the connection garbage. I just want to tell windows, "Mount everything that you already know how to mount."
This is all information that our computer services people have already figured out and configured on all our machines.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `net use /?` and read the output help. But there is no need to map the shared folder to drive letter `R:`. It is possible to simply use the [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Universal_Naming_Convention) of the shared folder. Please read also [Windows Environment Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) and use in future `%UserProfile%` instead of `c:\Users\%username%`.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I needed, thanks. I was obsessing with the wrong command "mountvol" which was a dead-end. I ended up going to my IT department and they gave me a solution that is really much more complicated than this (but I used it because it works). Now I'll do it this way. thanks, again.